# Remove Duplicates from List of HashMap Entries

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a `List<HashMap<String,Object>>` which represents a database where each list record is a database row.

I have 10 columns in my database. There are several rows where the values of 2 particular columns are equals. I need to remove the duplicates from the list after the list is updated with all the rows from database.

What is the efficient way?

FYI - I am not able to do distinct while querying the database, because the GroupName is added at a later stage to the `Map` after the database is loaded. And since Id column is not primary key, once you add GroupName to the `Map`. You will have duplicates based on Id + GroupName combination!

Hope my question makes sense. Let me know if we need more clarification.

Comment: The question: which ones needs to be removed and which one needs to be kept?

Comment: Why do you insert the duplicates in the first place? I mean, why don't you check for duplicates while inserting?

Comment: I already gave the reason in my question. The values in the HashMap are updated after the initial load from database. So is the reason I can apply the duplicate condition in the first place.

Comment: I suspect you *can* eliminate duplicates while querying the database.  Please post the SQL code, maybe as a separate question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create a Comparator that compares HashMaps, and compares them by comparing the key/value pairs you are interested in.
2. use `Collections.sort(yourlist, yourcomparator)`;
3. Now all maps that are similar to each other, based on your comparator, are adjacent in the list.
4. Create a new list.
5. Iterate through your first list, keeping track of what you saw last. If the current value is different than the last, add this to your new list.
6. You new list should contain no duplicates according to your comparator.

The cost of iterating through the list is O(n). Sorting is O(n log n). So this algorithm is O(n log n).

We could also sort on-the-fly by using a TreeSet with that comparator. Inserts are O(log n). And we have to do this n times. So we get O(n log n).

Comment: I hope this solution is also efficient even if my list has over 1~ Million rows !

Comment: It may be worth noting that with most Collections, HashMap included, you can simply remove() the duplicate object.  With HashMap, you pass the key to remove().  So you won't need a duplicate List or Map.

Comment: What are those 1 million rows doing in Java's memory? Why are you practically duplicating the DB in Java's memory? I think the problem needs to be solved somewhere else. Just update straight in DB instead of in Java's memory and make use of constraints to prevent duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I have taken an Employee class 
and created Map with Integer,Employee object as key-value pair
here is my Map

```
Map<Integer,Employee> map = new HashMap<Integer,Employee>();
```

Employee class is a bean class and it has properties like name,id,designation;
map allow unique keys. but if you don't want to allow duplicate values
in your map you have to over ride equals method in bean class.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object object){
    if (object == null) return false;
    if (object == this) return true;
    if (this.getClass() != object.getClass())return false;
    Employee employee = (Employee)object;
    if(this.hashCode()== employee.hashCode())return true;
   return false;
}
```

and while adding key-value to Map you have to use contains method

```
if(!map.containsValue(map.get(id))){
   map.put(id,employee);
}
```

`containsValue` internally calls `equals()` method and hence you over ride equals method
it will check every value(object) with previous objects and if hash codes are same
it returns true means both are same objects.

Answer (score 1):

I was having same condition, after lot of search, finally below solution worked for me.

1. Create POJO, override **equal**() & **hashCode**().
2. equality should be on all data members with .equal comparison.
3. Hashcode calculated as `Objects.hash(filed1, field2, ...)`;
4. Iterate over list and **construct** POJO object and **add** it to HashSet

Below is code -

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if( this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if( null == obj || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    Pojo rest = (Pojo) obj;
    return field1.equals(rest.field1) && field2.equals(rest.field2) && field3.equals(rest.field3); 
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(field1, field2, field3);
}

Set<Pojo> pathSet = new HashSet<>();
//Iterate over list and construct pojo object here
Pojo pojo = new Pojo(value1, value2, value3)
pathSet.add(pojo)
```

Thanks,