# Comparator that can compare LinkedHashMaps

Tags: java

I am new to `Comparators` in Java

Can someone help me to create a `Comparator` to compare `LinkedHashmaps` by comparing keys/values?

Comment: Can you explain a little more?  Give an example of a pair of LinkedHashMaps and why the one would be considered less than the other?  Note that a comparator of LinkedHashMaps is an extremely irregular thing to ever want to do, even for experts. Could it be that you really just want to know if they're equal, not which is greater?

Comment: **I am trying to remove duplicate linkedhashmap entries from a List Here is the pseudo code  ** 

    1. create a Comparator that compares HashMaps, and compares them by comparing the key/value pairs you are interested in.
    2. use Collections.sort(yourlist, yourcomparator);
    3. Now all maps that are similar to each other, based on your comparator, are adjacent in the list.
    4. Create a new list.
    5. Iterate through your first list, keeping track of what you saw last. If the current value is different than the last, add this to your new list.new list should contain no duplicates  .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195455/remove-duplicates-from-list-of-hashmap-entries - This is related to the question at the above link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample Pseudo-code. It does not handle nulls (which can be added if you want) and compares Map and a Map will not be very different/difficult :). There is a test case and lot of lines wasted to actually set up a list of maps, but should be easy to follow.

```
package com.ekanathk;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Test;

class MapEntryComparator implements Comparator<Map<String, String>> {

    private String[] keysToCompare;

    //What are the key columns you want to compare ???
    public MapEntryComparator(String[] keysToCompare) {
        this.keysToCompare = keysToCompare;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Map<String, String> o1, Map<String, String> o2) {
        for(String s: keysToCompare) {
            //HANDLE NULLS if any
            int comparison = o1.get(s).compareTo(o2.get(s));
            if(comparison != 0) {
                return comparison;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

}
public class ComparatorCheck {

    @Test
    public void testSimple() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> m1 = getMapSample("X", "M", "C", "D");
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> m2 = getMapSample("A", "B", "C", "D");
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> m3 = getMapSample("A", "B", "C", "D");
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> m4 = getMapSample("A", "B", "X", "D");

        List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();
        list.add(m1);
        list.add(m2);
        list.add(m3);
        list.add(m4);

        MapEntryComparator comparator = new MapEntryComparator(new String[]{"k1", "k2", "k3"});

        Collections.sort(list, comparator);

        assertEquals(m2, list.get(0));
        assertEquals(m3, list.get(1));
        assertEquals(m4, list.get(2));
        assertEquals(m1, list.get(3));
    }

    private LinkedHashMap<String, String> getMapSample(String v1, String v2, String v3, String v4) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("k1", v1);
        map.put("k2", v2);
        map.put("k3", v3);
        map.put("k4", v4);
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each `Map`(actually, all subclasses of `AbstractMap`) has already implemented the `equals(..)` method in a way that it compares the key/value pairs.

So, if using a `Comparator`, you can use:

```
public int compare(Map first, Map second){ 
       // appropriate null checks here
       return first.equals(second) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

---

But I'd rather put the `Map`s in a new `HashSet`, which will automatically remove duplicates:

```
Set<Map> uniqueMaps = new HashSet<Map>(listOfMaps);
```

Comment: This is not true, if you have 2 linked hash maps with same elements (key/value entries) but in different order, `equals` would return true while comparing elements should return false.

Comment: I've just tested with two LinkedHashMap with the same elements but in different order and the `equals` returned false.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this: (psuedocode)

```
for(each entry in firstList) {
    a=firstList.nextKey();
    b=secondList.nextKey();
    if(a != b !! firstList.get(a) != firstList.get(b))
        return false;
}
return true;
```

but that implies that you are using object identity (in otherwords, each object must be the same exact object in both lists).

If this isn't the case you have to implement .equals in every single object that might be in either list, then replace:

```
if(a != b ...
```

with

```
if(!a.equals(b)...
```

or something like that.

Also, as someone said in the comments, there is a really good chance that there is a better way than this to solve whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: this is a simpler solution than implementing a comparator (if you have to compare only in one place of your code). however I guess why Java Standard Library doesn' have a default equality comparator for linked hash maps... :/. +1 by the way.